# Python one-line "for" expression

Tags: python, lambda

I'm not sure if I need a lambda, or something else. But still, I need the following:

I have an `array = [1,2,3,4,5]`. I need to put this array, for instance, into another array. But write it all in one line.

```
for item in array:
    array2.append(item)
```

I know that this is completely possible to iterate through the items and make it one-line. But googling and reading manuals didn't help me that much... if you can just give me a hint or name this thing so that I could find what that is, I would really appreciate it.

**Update:** let's say this: `array2 = SOME FANCY EXPRESSION THAT IS GOING TO GET ALL THE DATA FROM THE FIRST ONE`

(the example is NOT real. I'm just trying to iterate through different chunks of data, but that's the best I could come up with)

Answer (score 153, accepted):

The keyword you're looking for is [list comprehensions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/):

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> y = [2*a for a in x if a % 2 == 1]
>>> print(y)
[2, 6, 10]
```

Comment: I'm still a beginner with Python, what's the purpose of this: "2*a"? @Adam Rosenfield

Comment: @Ahmad A bit late, but hopefully it can help someone else.
`a` gets assigned every element in the list `x` (because the for loop). So, the `2*a` is simply just taking every element in the list x and multiplying it by two. The doubled values will be in `y` after it's done iterating through the entire list `x`

Answer (score 36):

```
for item in array: array2.append (item)
```

Or, in this case:

```
array2 += array
```

Answer (score 5):

If you really only need to add the items in one array to another, the '+' operator is already overloaded to do that, incidentally:

```
a1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
a2 = [6,7,8,9]
a1 + a2
--> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 4):

Even `array2.extend(array1)` will work.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to *copy* the array:

```
array2 = array[:]
```